# Desativar a possibilidade da tecla ENTER atuar na ação de outro botão

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá, pessoal.

Estou com um formulário no qual possui dois tables, dentro da segunda table possui um input text [sinal 1 da imagem]. Esse input text faz a pesquisa do registro quando pressionado a tecla ENTER.

Porém quando aperto o ENTER ele está ativando um botão class"accordion" [sinal 2 da imagem] e fechando (ou abrindo), além de realizar a pesquisa.

Como que faço para desabilitar essa ação quando aperto a tecla ENTER?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

action para abrir e fechar o accordion

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('submit','form', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
   });
   $(document).on('submit','div', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
   });
   $('.collapse').show();
});
```

função js para realizar a pesquisa

```
function pesquisar(element){
   $(document).on('submit','form', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
   });

   $('#' + element.id).keyup(function(e){  
      if(e.keyCode == 13){
      ... chama um ajax para chamar outro arquivo PHP para fazer a pesquisa
```

tela.php

```
    <form>
    <!--- tabela - 1 -->
    <div class="row" id="cx_1">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 espaco1">
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordionN1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <button id="b1" class="accordion"
                                ><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                            </button>
                        <div style=" padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 12px;" class="panel-collapse collapse" 
                                role="tabpanel">
                            <div style="padding: 5px;">
                                <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" style="font-size: 11px;">
                                    <td>...</td>
                                </table>    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!--- tabela 2 -->
    <div class="row" id="cx_2">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 espaco1">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordionN2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <button id="b2" class="accordion"
                                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Passagem de Serviço</button>
                    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
                        <div style="padding: 5px;">
                            <table id="table_linha_passagem_servico" class="table table-condensed table-hover" style="font-size: 11px;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">Serviço</th>
                                        <th class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">Descrição</th>
                                        <th class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">Fiscal Elab.</th>
                                        <th class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">Fiscal Envio</th>
                                        <th class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">Enviado em</th>
                                        <th class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">Avaliação</th>
                                        <th class="col-xs-0.4 col-sm-0.4"></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr id="linha_passagem_servico_row1">
                                        <td><input style="height: 25px; font-size:12px; width: 100px" 
                                            class="form-control"  type ="text" id="servico_passagem_servico_row1"
                                            onkeydown="pesquisar(this)"></td>
                                        <td id="descricao_passagem_servico_row1"></td>
                                        <td><input class="form-control upper" style="height: 25px; font-size:12px; width: 45px; padding-left: 5px;"  maxlength="4" type ="text" id="fiscal_elab_passagem_servico_row1"></td>
                                        <td><input class="form-control upper" style="height: 25px; font-size:12px; width: 45px; padding-left: 5px;"  maxlength="4" type ="text" id="fiscal_envio_passagem_servico_row1"></td>
                                        <td><input class="form-control data" style="height: 25px; font-size:12px; width: 120px" pattern="^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$"  type ="text" id="data_envio_passagem_servico_row1"></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select 
                                                style="height: 25px; font-size:12px; width: 120px" id="avaliacao_passagem_servico_row1"
                                                name="avaliacao_passagem_servico" class="form-control">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                                <option value="7,5">7,5</option>
                                                <option value="5,0">5</option>
                                                <option value="2,5">2,5</option>
                                                <option value="0,0">0</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;" ><button id="excluir_passagem_servico_row1" type="button" style="height: 25px; width: 30px" onclick="excluirLinha(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>        
                            <div class="row" >
                                <div class="col-sm-12" >
                                    <br>
                                        <button type="button" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; float: right;" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_passagem_servico" onclick="adicionarLinhaPassagemServico()"  >Adicionar Linha</button>
                                        <button type="button" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; float: left;" class="btn btn-primary" id="salvar_passagem_servico" onclick="salvarPassagemServico()" >Salvar Avaliação</button>              
                                </div>
                            </div>                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: As vezes isso pode te ajudar... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542413/bind-enter-key-to-specific-button-on-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando um `onkeydown` no `input` apenas para chamar a função `pesquisar()` para enviar o `id` do `input` para um evento `keyup`. Não precisa fazer isso. Além de tudo irá bugar seu código criando inúmeros eventos repetidos cada vez que uma tecla é pressionada.

O que você precisa fazer é criar um evento único que irá pegar o `id` do campo digitado. Adicione uma classe qualquer para todos os campos onde será clicado o ENTER (no caso abaixo, coloquei a classe `.servnum` no `input`). Essa classe será usada no evento `.on('keyup'...`, e remova do `input` o `onkeydown="pesquisar(this)"`. O `input` ficará assim:

```
                                                                          classe adicionada
                                                                                 ↓
<input style="height: 25px; font-size:12px; width: 100px" class="form-control servnum"  type ="text" id="servico_passagem_servico_row1">
```

Outra coisa é adicionar um `type="button"` no botão `.accordion` para que ele se comporte como um botão comum e não submeta o formulário ao ser clicado:

```
                     ↓
<button id="b2" type="button" class="accordion" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Passagem de Serviço</button>
```

Além do que você está abrindo o `collapse` de forma errada. Seria

`$('.collapse').collapse('show');` em vez de `$('.collapse').show();`

Feito isso, coloque todo o código JS dentro do `$(document).ready(function() {`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('submit','form', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
   });
   $(document).on('submit','div', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
   });

   $('.collapse').collapse('show');

   $(document).on('keyup', '.servnum', function(e){  
      var this_id = this.id; // id do campo
      if(e.keyCode == 13){
         // chama o Ajax
      }
   });
});
```